# Is there a way to have this done implicitly?

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit

Is there any way to have this implicit method called on x before it matches to meet the type requirements of the match?

If I call it directly it works as expected, but I would like to know if it's possible for the call to be inferred.

```
object ImplicitTest extends App {
  implicit def denull[T<:Any](mightBeNull:T):Option[T] = {
    if (mightBeNull == null) None
    else Some(canBeNull)
  }

  var x:String = null
  x match {  //works if i do "denull(x) match {"
    case Some(str:String) =>
      println(str)
    case None => None
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap this with method which uses implicit convertion if you want:

```
def print[A](opt: Option[A]) = opt.foreach(println)
```

When you call this method on variable with null value, Scala compiler resolves your implicit convertion method `denull`, and if it isn't `None`, will print it.
But you can simply do this without `denull` method:

```
var str: String = null
Option(str).foreach(println)
```

Scala won't resolve implicit conversion in pattern matching, because has no idea that it needs to be converted to some other type. Such way of conversion is a mechanism against type errors, when compiler can do "the last try" and use some value with type `A` in place where type `B` needed. In pattern matching you just match against type or other things

Answer (score 6):

Instead of your `denull` method you should use `Option.apply`. It does the same thing. Possible null values should always be handled explicitly! Implicit conversion is dangerous and can be confusing for other people who have to work with your code. Do it like this:

```
Option(x) match {}
```

or in most cases even better:

```
Option(x).fold { ... } { ... }
```

Comment: I never planned on using this for any production code, just for learning concepts, but thank you for the advice